# Spring + Kotlin + Gradle + Multi module - configuration

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle, multi-module

I have a project written in Kotlin with Spring and Gradle. https://github.com/skoczman/oremus/tree/main

I have two problems:

1. Gradle configuration - Gradle is building successful now, but I'm not sure, is configuration nice written.
2. I'm creating EditionService.class (https://github.com/skoczman/oremus/blob/main/app-runner/src/main/kotlin/pl/oazapraga/oremus/app/edition/EditionServiceConfiguration.kt) manually and I cannot do this properly -> when app is running, and service method is called, it's  appear that "this.repository is null".

Can I ask you to make review on this two points and give some suggestions, what should be fixed? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
I made a progress: I add "open" to findAll fun:

```
 open fun findAll(): List<Edition> {
    return repository.findAll()
}
```

W would like to add allOpen  plugin in that case - can you help to configure it under Gradle?

Comment: I see that `EditionRepository` is defined in different module `jpa-repository`. But I did not find any [@EnableJpaRepositories](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-annotations#5-enablejparepositories) annotation on some persistence configuration class. This annotation on some configuration will enable creation of the `EditionRepository`.

Comment: But module with EditionRepository is imported in build.gradle of app-runner module. And package name matches. It is not enough?